# string replace using Linq in c#

Tags: linq, string, replace, using

```
public class Abbreviation
{
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string LongName { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of Abbreviation objects like this:

```
List abbreviations = new List();
abbreviations.add(new Abbreviation() {ShortName = "exp.", LongName = "expression"});
abbreviations.add(new Abbreviation() {ShortName = "para.", LongName = "paragraph"});
abbreviations.add(new Abbreviation() {ShortName = "ans.", LongName = "answer"});

string test = "this is a test exp. in a para. contains ans. for a question";

string result = test.Replace("exp.", "expression")
...
```

I expect the result to be:
"this is a test expression in a paragraph contains answer for a question"

Currently I am doing:

```
foreach (Abbreviation abbreviation in abbreviations)
{
    test = test.Replace(abbreviation.ShortName, abbreviation.LongName);
}
result = test;
```

Wondering if there is a better way using a combination of Linq and Regex.

Comment: LINQ isn't a solution to every problem, what you have written is fine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you really wanted to shorten your code, you could use the `ForEach` extension method on the `List`:

```
abbreviations.ForEach(x=> test=test.Replace(x.ShortName, x.LongName));
```

Comment: technically this isn't LINQ ;-)

Comment: technically it's not functional programming either - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: I knew there is always a better way than what I normally do. It works great. Thanks to you and Mike.

Comment: i want the same but how do i find part of string and replace it with some other text ? please suggest.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the ForEach method. Also, a StringBuilder should make the operations on your string more efficient:

```
var test = new StringBuilder("this is a test exp. in a para. contains ans. for a question");
abbreviations.ForEach(abb => test = test.Replace(abb.ShortName, abb.LongName));
return test.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
TestList.ForEach(x => x.TestType.Replace("", "DataNotAvailable"));
```

or the one below

```
foreach (TestModel item in TestList.Where(x => x.ID == ""))
{
    item.ID = "NoDataAvailable";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

var newList = someList.Select(s => s.Replace("XX", "1")).ToList();