# How to replace a string with linq

Tags: string, linq, replace

I have this bit of code that joins 3 tables. In the end, the result is a list of users.
The list that is returned usually contains records like "DG3\RONASS", but can also be DG4, DG5, etc.
In this case, I'm replacing "DG3\" just to see how it works. How can I make it generic, so that it replaces the backslash and everything before it, without having to specify a string to replace like in this case?

```
 List<string> journalingUsers = Context.ResourceSetSet
                .Join(Context.ResourceItemJnSet, resourceSet => resourceSet.ID, resourceItemJn => resourceItemJn.ResourceSet_ID, (resourceSet, resourceItemJn) => new { ResourceSet = resourceSet, ResourceItemJn = resourceItemJn }).Where(join => join.ResourceSet.ToepassingsCode == toepassingsCode).Select(join => join.ResourceItemJn).ToList()
                .Join(Context.ResourceItemDotNetJnSet, resourceItemJn => resourceItemJn.ID, resourceItemDotNetJn => resourceItemDotNetJn.ID, (resourceItemJn, resourceItemDotNetJn) => new { ResourceItemJn = resourceItemJn, ResourceItemDotNetJn = resourceItemDotNetJn }).Select(join => join.ResourceItemDotNetJn).ToList()
                .Join(Context.ResourceItemWaardeJnSet, resourceItemDotNetJn => resourceItemDotNetJn.ID, resourceItemWaardeJn => resourceItemWaardeJn.ResourceItem_ID, (resourceItemDotNetJn, resourceItemWaardeJn) => new { ResourceItemDotNetJn = resourceItemDotNetJn, ResourceItemWaardeJn = resourceItemWaardeJn })
     .Select(join => join.ResourceItemWaardeJn.User.Replace(@"DG3\", ""))
     .Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: You just want to return everything after the backslash??

Comment: Right margin Overflow.

Comment: yes, that's it, DavidG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Substring` function:

```
journalingUsers = journalingUsers.Select(s => s.Substring(s.IndexOf(@"\")+1));
```

Comment: +1, more efficient and more redable than my string.split approach

Comment: Don't think you should have deleted yours though, it's still a valid answer.

Comment: Ok, i've undeleted it. Maybe it has some added value if OP needs to take/skip other parts.

Comment: Works like a charm, tks.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to ignore the first part? A simple approach is using `String.Split` and `Enumerable.Skip`:

```
List<string> allButFirst = journalingUsers
    .Select(s => string.Join("\\", s.Split('\\').Skip(1)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: It's not a path, just `Domain\User` so you don't need to Join again. `Split(...)[2]` is enough.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: You've lost me. OP doesn't mention `Domain\User` or that it contains three tokens.

Comment: Yeah, should have been `[1]`

Answer (score -1):

This question on #Stackoverflow might help you out, check it out?

[Link to Question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137514/string-replace-using-linq-in-c-sharp)