# C# Linq Expression to remove from string if found in an array

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple function that loops through a static string array and tests to see if a string contains any instance of the array. If true, then the text from the string is removed (replaced with an empty string).

This function works, but I need to create a LINQ expression to do this (or a one-line expression). I can't figure out how to do this unless I turn my string **s** into an array. But if I do that then it complicates trying to match the **facilities** strings. How can I accomplish this in a one-liner?

```
  private static string[] facilities = { "MX10", "MX80", "MX81", "MX82", "MX83", "US00", "US10", "US11", "US20", "US30", "US50", "US60", "US70", "US99" };
  
  private static string cleansePN(string s)
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < facilities.Length; i++)
      {
          s = s.Replace(facilities[i], string.Empty);
      }
      return s;
  }
```

Comment: If the facilities array really is static, have you considered just making a RegEx from it?  RegEx replace would be the simpler and faster than LINQ over an array.

Comment: @IanMercer I like this... so its essentially  `return Regex.Replace(s, @"MX10|MX80|...", string.Empty); `

Comment: Maybe `Regex r = new Regex("MX[0-9]+|US[0-9]+", RegexOptions.Compiled);` if you want to catch all MX and US followed by one or more digits. Or you could make it more precise if it's always two digits.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [string replace using Linq in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137514/string-replace-using-linq-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linq [Aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-5.0):

```
private static string cleansePN(string s)
{
    return facilities.Aggregate(s, (current, t) => current.Replace(t, string.Empty));
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Would you say that the for loop is faster (given a string of 10-30 characters) or is it negligible?

Comment: @bagofmilk `Aggregate` uses inside `foreach`, so, it's equal